# Difference between pointer receiver and load func

Tags: go, struct

Let's say I have a struct like this:

```
type MyService struct {
    name string
    region string
    environment string 
}
```

If there are many fields in the struct, I can set them using pointer receivers:

```
func (m *MyService) Name(name string) {
  m.name = name  
}
func (m *MyService) Region(region string) {
  m.region = region  
}
```

The other option, I have seen in 3rd party libraries or SDK's, is:

```
type MyServiceLoadOptions func(service *MyService) error
```

And set fields like:

```
func WithRegion(region string) MyServiceLoadOptions {

    return func(service *MyService) error {
        service.region = region
        return nil
    }
}

func WithName(name string) MyServiceLoadOptions {

    return func(service *MyService) error {
        service.name = name
        return nil
    }
}
```

And get it like:

```
myService, err = MyServiceNew(WithName("newName"), WithRegion("us-east-1"))   

func MyServiceNew(options ...MyServiceLoadOptions) (*MyService, error) {

    
    service := &MyService{}


    for _, option := range options {
        err := option(service)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }
    return service, nil
}
```

What is the advantage of using function loader vs pointer receiver to set fields?

I see the latter option  used in AWS Golang SDK's.

Comment: For one, it makes the instance properties unmodifiable from outside of the package. The only time the values can be set is in the `New` function that creates the instance.

Comment: The second option is a wrapper that can be extended, i.e. can do more things in those functions before assignment, add additional layers etc.

Comment: @sberry is only partially correct. The properties can still be modified trough the accessor functions if you have access to the instance, since the functions are public them self. On the other hand, you can no longer read properties on the instance, unless there is a method for reading as well.

Comment: Functional options are not meant to replace setters, rather it is a very extensible way of doing constructors, way easier to maintain backwards compatibility over time. This article explains it very nicely: https://golang.cafe/blog/golang-functional-options-pattern.html